# How To Count the tickets (Tickets) that created on a date (X) before certain date (M) and Solved after (M)

Tags: oracle

I need to retrieve the "Count of Solved tickets" that were created before the 'Created Date" and solved after the "created date" group by the "Created date" Column using ORACLE SQL

```
Ticket# Created_Date Solved_Date
3315279 12-MAR-19   15-MAR-19
3355379 10-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
3378633 11-MAR-19   15-MAR-19
3470592 13-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3472784 13-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3472930 13-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3473119 13-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3474194 11-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
3721765 12-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3723124 12-FEB-19   16-MAR-19
3723286 07-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
3724733 05-MAR-19   16-MAR-19
3724894 03-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
3750270 09-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
3751118 06-MAR-19   14-MAR-19
```

From comments:

- 12-MAR-19: 8 as there are 8 Tickets created before that date and solved after it.
- 10-MAR-19: 5 as there are 5 Tickets created before that date and solved after it.

Comment: Post your expected results and explain what exactly you need.

Comment: 12-MAR-19     8  
as there are 8 Tickets created before that date and solved after it.

10-MAR-19     5 
as there are 5 Tickets created before that date and solved after it.

Comment: as i'm creating a report with these analysis : Count of created tickets , Count OF Solved Tickets , OLD Tickets that didn't solve group by created date and for ex: 12-Mar-2019 Has 8 OLD Tickets Solved after it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query -

```
select t1.creation_date,count(t1.ticketno) as count
from ticket_demo t1, ticket_demo t2 
where t2.creation_date <t1.creation_date and t2.solved_date>t1.creation_date 
group by t1.creation_date;

TICKETNO    CREATION_DATE   SOLVED_DATE
1   01-01-18    12-04-18
2   01-12-17    04-01-18
3   01-11-17    01-01-18
4   01-02-18    28-02-18
5   03-04-18    04-05-18
6   01-04-18    04-05-18
7   01-01-18    05-06-18
```

O/P -

```
CREATION_DATE   COUNT
03-04-18    3
01-04-18    2
01-02-18    2
01-01-18    2
01-12-17    1
```

Comment: Thanks Atul , kindly be noted that i'm using the Oracle 11G XE and the Query still Running

`SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(F.COMPLAINT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') TDay , COUNT(F.TEL_NO) AS COUNT 
From
    Closed F , Closed S
Where 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(S.COMPLAINT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(F.COMPLAINT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
AND
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(S.Close_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(F.COMPLAINT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
Group BY 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(F.COMPLAINT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY
    1 DESC`

Comment: Please , any support as i didn't get the required result , the Query still running without and didn't retrieve any thing just running .